# jquery barcode scanner without using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, html5-video, barcode-scanner, cordova-2.0.0

We are looking into the development of a mobile web app where we need to have barcode scanning functionality.  The application needs to run on iPhone and iPad tablets.  I know PhoneGap (Cordova) offers a barcode scanner plugin.  I've used it in an iOS app previously.  Our new application does not need to be distributed via app store.  We are looking at simply creating a website shortcut to place the web app on the home screen of the user's iPhone/iPad.  (see http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/06/19/how-create-website-shortcuts-iphone-homescreen/).

So, is it possible to use the PhoneGap barcode scanner plugin without creating an iPhone application?  Are there other plugins that will allow a web app to interact with a device's camera to read a barcode?  I know with HTML5 you can access a device's camera.  I'm not sure how to read a barcode though.  Or, is the only way to read a barcode is to create an iOS application?

Thanks for any help you can lend while we are planning our application's architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect javascript to binary api functionality without writing an actual app first.  The camera can be used on newer versions of Safari, and you could upload the photo that is taken to a server for backend processing.